Specifying tab when exporting Google Doc as PDF via Google Drive API?
I'm wondering if it's possible to specify the tab (recently added to Google Docs) when exporting as PDF via the Google Drive API? (https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId}/export)
I can't find anything about it in the documentation. Anyone else figured this out?
Tried finding it in the documentation, but no luck.

Could you please elaborate on this specify the tab (recently added to Google Docs)?

Sorry I meant tabs in Google Docs. See documentation here: https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/tabs

I guessed that this answer might be an answer to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/79183961

It is not because it refers to Apps Script and not the API

Currently, there is no direct documentation about exporting specific tabs in Google Docs through the API.

Check if this similar issue (Getting the HTML or PDF of a Google Doc includes a page/heading with the Tab name) resolves your query.

This is indeed the post on Google's issue tracker, where I've commented already. Thank you!
